# ElementCollection returning Null in JSON response

Tags: hibernate, hashmap, hql, dropwizard

I have the following declaration of elementCollection

In class MyMainClass

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyMainClass")
referencedColumnName="id"))
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "=findAll",  
        query = "SELECT s FROM MyMainClass s")})

public class MyMainClass  implements Comparable<MyMainClass>, Serializable {


        @JsonProperty
        @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
        @Column
        Map<String,String> myMap;

public void setMyMap(Map<String,String> myMap) {
this.myMap = myMap;
}

public Map<String,String> getMyMap() {
return this.myMap;
}


}
```

This creates a table `MyMainClass_myMap`

```
mymainclass_id mymapvalue mymapkey


public List<MyMainClass> findAll(String param) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<MyMainClass> myMainClass = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM MyMainClass  WHERE param = :param ;
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("param", param);
        query.addEntity(MyMainClass.class);
        myMainClass = query.list();
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
        tx.rollback();
        }
        throw e;

    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return myMainClass;

    }
```

With values nut the JSOn returns null. why is that?

Comment: Could you please provide more context? Show us the entire `MyMainClass` entity, the code that retrieves the entity from JPA etc. Note that collections of elements are lazily fetched by default

Comment: can I change the fetchType to eager

Comment: You can try, but without seeing the code, I cannot guarantee it will help

Comment: ok going to try, i added the missing bits. what would you suggest is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a named query to retrieve all instances of `MyMainClass` but inside `findAll`, you've used an SQL query. Why is that? Your SQL query only retrieves data from the `MyMainClass` table.

What you should do is load the entities using the query obtained from `session.getNamedQuery("=findAll")`. In order for the entities to have their `myMap` populated, you can either:

1. Mark the element collection as eagerly fetched using JPA annotations (`@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`)
2. Mark the element collection as eagerly fetched using Hibernate annotations (`@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`)
3. Use a fetch join in your named query (`SELECT s FROM MyMainClass s LEFT JOIN FETCH s.myMap`)
4. Initialize `myMap` before closing the session (by calling `Hibernate.initialize(entity.getMyMap())` on each entity retrieved from the query, for instance)

Options #2 and #3 will likely be the most performant. Note that options #1 and #2 will cause `myMap` to be eagerly fetched whenever instances of `MyMainClass` are retrieved from the `Session`. If that is your intention, that would probably be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much for explaining this.